# Pipe mutiple api calls to cient with node/express/request

Tags: json, node.js, api, express, request

I have a web app for the steam api that is working fine with a single server side api call. But I would like to pipe two or more api calls to the client. Currently the below code works, how do I send second_json to the client?

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

function proxy() {
    app.use('/', function(req, res) {
        var sid = req.query.sid[1].trim();
        var url ="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=[APIKEY]&steamids=";
        var url2 ="http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=[APIKEY]&vanityurl=";
        var url3 =  "http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=[APIKEY]&steamid=";
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        request(url2 + sid, function(error, response, body) {
            var newid = JSON.parse(body).response.steamid
            if (newid !== undefined) {
                sid = newid;
            }
            request(url3+sid+"&format=json", function(err, resp, result){
               var second_json = result;
               req.pipe(request(url + sid)).pipe(res);
            })
        });
    });
}
proxy();
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you  send `second_json` in any response. I see where you declare it, but not where you use it anywhere in your code.

Comment: exactly, i don't know how to send it. I cannot call req.pipe twice and I cannot append second_json to res. I do not know how to either pipe two things, or concat both jsons and pipe with the correct cors headers

Comment: You should change your question to reflect that. Ask 'how do I send' instead of 'it is not sending'.

Comment: @Nocturno I edited for clarity